# $\mathbb{E}[X V^TVX^T]$ =?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, expectation

Assume $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)$, $X\in \mathbb{R}^{Nx2}$ and $V\in \mathbb{R}^{2x2}$ is a matrix of constants

I'm trying to find out how to evaluate:
$$\mathbb{E}[X V^TVX^T]$$

When the $X's$ are on the inside this is easy: $$\mathbb{E}[VXX^TV^T] = V\mathbb{E}[X^TX]V^T = VIV^T$$

But I cant wrap my head around when the $X$'s are on the outside... Any hints?

Comment: I would try taking the eigen-decomposition of $V^T V.$ Then I think you can decompose the product as a (weighted) sum of two outer products of  multivariate normal vectors with covariance matrices that can be determined using standard facts about linear transformations of multivariate normals.

Comment: Does the assumption $X\sim {\mathcal N}(0,1)$ refer to the rows, or the columns, of the $N\times 2 $ matrix, or something else? Are the rows/columns independent?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The matrix $XV^TVX^T$ is an $n\times n$ matrix of random variables, so its expectation is defined elementwise. To find the expectation of the $(i,j)$ element of this matrix, go back to the definition of matrix multiplication:
$$
(XV^TVX^T)_{i,j}=\sum_k\sum_l X_{i,k}(V^TV)_{k,l}(X^T)_{l,j}
=\sum_k\sum_l (V^TV)_{k,l} X_{i,k}X_{j,l}\tag1
$$
and then apply expectation to (1), which is a linear combination of random variables:
$$
{\mathbb E}[(XV^TVX^T)_{i,j}]=\sum_k\sum_l (V^TV)_{k,l}{\mathbb E}[ X_{i,k}X_{j,l}]\tag2
$$
Now compute ${\mathbb E}[ X_{i,k}X_{j,l}]$ using what you know about the joint distribution of the elements of $X$.

It's not clear if the rows or the columns of $X$ follow a ${\mathcal N}(0,I)$ distribution, so I'll leave it to you to finish the calculation. Note that ${\mathbb E}[ X_{i,k}X_{j,l}]$ will be zero for certain combinations of $i,j,k,l$, which causes simplification in (2).

Comment: The columns of $X$ are two time series, each which are IID across time and independent of each other. i.e. the columns correspond to the time series and the rows indicate time. Does that simplify it at all?